# How to Pen Test REST API which is secured with jwt

Tags: rest, spring-boot, ws-security, zap

I have a RESt API which is secured with JWT token (As a HTTP header). I want to do a Penetration Test on the TEST API and have no prior understanding in this topic.So i went through some guidance and I installed OWASP ZAP and typed the URL and pressed the attack button.But the response was

```
Failed to attack the URL :received a 401 response code
```

So how can pen test my REST API using ZAP?

Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you generate a valid JWT token in some way?
If so you can then tell ZAP to use it as explained in this blog post: https://zaproxy.blogspot.com/2017/06/scanning-apis-with-zap.html

Comment: Yeah I can generate a valid token.Let me try this.thanks.Btw is there GUI Examples

Comment: You can do all of the above via the UI - see the previous blog post (https://zaproxy.blogspot.co.uk/2017/04/exploring-apis-with-zap.html) for some details. If you need more help ask here or maybe ask on the ZAP User Group? https://groups.google.com/group/zaproxy-users

Comment: Do I need to write scripts for the test or could it done by just passing the url and the token as a header.

Comment: You can do everything that the cmdline script does using the UI without any scripts :)

Comment: If u don't mind can we continue this discussion in a chat room since I have some issues and while testing the API's . Thank you

Comment: Sure: irc.mozilla.org #websectools is where you can usually find some of the ZAP core team :)

Comment: Again @SimonBennetts, these are most common scenarios, ZAP is a powerful tool but it would be great to have a full videos on how to test REST APIs with JWT etc..